# App crashes on capturing image/selecting image from gallery - Titanium Android

Tags: android, titanium, android-camera, titanium-mobile

I am trying to upload an image. Previously, it was working everything fine. Suddenly now it stopped working on Android. Tested the same code on iOS, works fine.

Use case:
1. Click on a button - Opens camera (or can select from gallery)
2. Capture an image
3. Press 'Ok' button - App crashes

I cleared lots of memory thinking that some devices may have memory issues. Added camera permissions according to the new release notes, still facing the issue. Here is my code:

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({
    options : ['Camera', 'Gallery', 'Cancel'],
    title : 'Upload image using?'
});

dialog.show();

dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if (e.index === 0) {

        //Open Camera
        Ti.Media.showCamera({
            saveToPhotoGallery : true,

            success : function(event) {
                console.error('UPLOAD IMAGE SUCCESS ', JSON.stringify(event));
                callback(event.media);
            },

            cancel : function(err) {
                console.error('UPLOAD IMAGE CANCEL ', JSON.stringify(err));
            },

            error : function(err) {
                console.error('UPLOAD IMAGE ERROR ', JSON.stringify(err));
            },

            showControls : true,
            mediaTypes : Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO,
            autohide : true
        });
    } else if (e.index === 1) {

        //Open gallery
        Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
            success : function(event) {
                console.error('UPLOAD IMAGE SUCCESS ', JSON.stringify(event));
                callback(event.media);
            },

            cancel : function(err) {
                console.error('UPLOAD IMAGE CANCEL ', JSON.stringify(err));
            },

            error : function(err) {
                console.error('UPLOAD IMAGE ERROR ', JSON.stringify(err));
            },
        });
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
    dialog.hide();
});
```

tiapp.xml

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>
```

Can anyone please tell what's wrong with the code or do I need to add anything else?

Some logs:

```
[DEBUG] :  skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[DEBUG] :  skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[DEBUG] :  skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[DEBUG] :  skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[DEBUG] :  skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
[DEBUG] :  Window: Window is closed normally.
```

Comment: Can you Post your Logcat..

Comment: I am not getting any debug logs while crashing.

Comment: Added some logs what I got before crash

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I needed to do two things.

1. Add this in tiapp.xml

   `<manifest>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
   </manifest>`
2. Open settings> Applications> Camera

   - Force close, then clear data and cache
   - Reboot the phone

This I used to solve, and it started working.

Comment: I believe this was the issue with the camera itself.